# What should I do if I want to print value of ' i ' when I clicked 'like[i]' button? Like when I click on 'Button 2' then it should give me value '2'

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jbutton

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class button_array extends JFrame{
    int i;
    JLabel[] ulb = new JLabel[4];
    JButton[] like = new JButton[4];
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    public button_array() {

        new JFrame();
        i =3;
        while(i>0) {
            ulb[i] = new JLabel("user "+i);
            like[i] = new JButton("Button "+i);
            
            
            panel.add(ulb[i]);
            panel.add(like[i]);
            panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(25));
            
            like[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            });
            
            i--;
        }
    
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    add(panel);
    setSize(400,400);
    setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new button_array();
    }
}
```

1. How do I get value id 'i' in action performed section. It gives value of 'i' as 0 for every button I clicked.
2. What should I do if I want to print value of ' i ' when i clicked 'like[i]' button. Like when I click on 'Button 2' then it should give me value '2'

[here's a link of screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpLUr.png)

Comment: Please don't link irrelevant screenshots. That one adds *nothing* that could not be explained in a few words.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
    System.out.println(i);
```

will not work because when you click, it will take the value of `i` at that moment, which is equal to 0, because of `i--` in the loop.

So, if you want to print the `index` of `JButton` in `like[]`, you could do like this in the override `actionPerformed`:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton o = (JButton)e.getSource();
                    
    for (int j = 0; j < like.length; j++)
    {                        
        if (like[j]!= null && (JButton)like[j] == o)
        {
            System.out.println(j);
        }
    }
}
```

or simply print the number character of `JButton.getText()`:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton o = (JButton)e.getSource();
    String str1 = o.getText();

    String str2 = str1.substring(6, str1.length());
    System.out.println(j);
}
```